Transformation in Proof of $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}\leq3$.
Let $a$, $b$, $c$ positive reals for which holds
$ab+bc+ca+abc=4$. It is possible to prove from this that
$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}\leq3$, see eg here
My question is the following: In this amazing argument Michael Rozenberg approached this problem by introducing certain transformation  $$a=\frac{2x}{y+z}, b=\frac{2y}{x+z}, c=\frac{2z}{x+y}$$ and turning the original problem into task to show
$$2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{xy}{(x+z)(y+z)}}\leq3 $$
*Question: From naive point of view to introduce exactly this trafo\substitution above appears to be more or less "magically fallen from the sky/coming from nowhere". Indeed, there is myriad of other possible transformations. Why conceptionally in order to attack this problem exactly this transformation is suitable (...beyond just that "it works")?
Is there a concept &  geometric intuition behind application of this transformation "reflecting" why in context of this problem this trafo is actually well suited for this problem, and as I noticed rather often applied in similar contest problems dealing with showing certain inequalities? So, for what "types" of problems this transformation could be regarded as "well suited" and what is the intuition& concept for exactly this one?
Ie in which sense is this trafo actually "distinguished"?
A nitpick: In terminology of contest math, what is a "$uvw$ proof" [#EDIT: nitpick part solved, see @lulu's link]
NB concerning the suggestions to close this question refering to its similarities with this one:
The related question there asks about how to prove $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}\leq3$. My question adresses explicitly the concrete technique used in the proof, not about how somehow to prove the claim from that linked question.

Here's a reference to the uvw method

@Angelo: Exactly this thread motivated actually my question! The question is not how to prove this - this is actually done in the proof of this linked discussion - but what is the concept of the used technique there? Namely, Michael Rozenberg introduce certain trafo, but the question is if the is a concept behind why to introduce this trafo and not say some other. Please, read again my question.

@user267839, just read this thread carefully and you will learn how to ask a good question.

@Angelo: Well, there are several points, but I not sure which of these points is carried out inferiorly in this question. Successful learning is linked to recognizing mistakes& improvable issues. I would like to suggest if you are interested in constructive conversation to point out the points from there whose fullfilling actually flaws in this question.

I don't know how the transformation was originally found. Below is only a post-hoc attempt.
From the condition, solve for $c$ to get
$$c=\frac{4-ab}{ab+a+b}.$$
Find $k$ such that the numberator + $k\times$denominator can be factored. I got $k=2$. So
$$
c+2=\frac{4-ab+2ab+2a+2b}{ab+a+b}=\frac{(a+2)(b+2)}{ab+a+b},
$$
and
$$\frac1{c+2}=\frac{ab+a+b}{(a+2)(b+2)}=\frac{(a+2)(b+2)-(a+2)-(b+2)}{(a+2)(b+2)}.
$$Therefore, $$
\frac1{a+2}+\frac1{b+2}+\frac1{c+2}=1.
$$
Naturally, we may consider the transformation
$$
\frac1{a+2}=\frac{A}{A+B+C},\ \frac1{b+2}=\frac{B}{A+B+C},\ \text{and }\frac1{c+2}=\frac{C}{A+B+C}, 
$$for positive $A$, $B$, and $C$. (If the inequality to be proved can be nicely written in $a+2$, $b+2$ and $c+2$, probably I'd just use this transformation.)
Solving for $c$ to get
$$c=\frac{A+B-C}{C}>0.
$$
Thus, $A$, $B$ and $C$ must be side lengths of a triangle. And the conventional substitution for sides of a triangle would be $A=y+z$, $B=x+z$ and $C=x+y$, leading to
$$
c=\frac{2z}{x+y}.
$$
